# Meteor.js onRendered not triggered for dynamic template on data change

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to integrate a dynamic template called "page-event" on "page-main" which depends on data from a helper:

HTML MAIN

```
{{>Template.dynamic template="page-event" data=selectedEvent}}
```

JS MAIN

```
Template["page-main"].helpers({
    selectedEvent: function() {
        var eventId = Template.instance().selectedEventId.get()
        event = Collections.Events.findOne(eventId);
        return { event: event };
    }
});
```

JS EVENT

```
Template["page-event"].onRendered(function() {
        const ti = this;
        var eventData = this.data.event;
        console.log("RENDERING EVENT");
        // Color picker
        var colorPicker = $(ti.find(".colorSelect"));
        colorPicker.colorpicker({ format: "hex" });
        colorPicker.colorpicker("setValue", eventData.color);
        colorPicker.colorpicker().on("hidePicker.colorpicker", function(event) {
            var rgb = event.color.toRGB();
            Meteor.call("setEventVsColor", eventData._id, "rgb(" + rgb.r.toString() + "," + rgb.g.toString() + "," + rgb.b.toString() + ")");
        });
});
```

JS EVENT (incl. Jankapunkt's solution)

```
    Template["page-event"].onRendered(function() {
            const ti = this;
            const data = Template.currentData()
            var eventData = data.event;
            ti.autorun( function() {
              console.log("RENDERING EVENT");
              // Color picker
              var colorPicker = $(ti.find(".colorSelect"));
              colorPicker.colorpicker({ format: "hex" });
              colorPicker.colorpicker("setValue", eventData.color);
              colorPicker.colorpicker().on("hidePicker.colorpicker", function(event) {
                var rgb = event.color.toRGB();
                Meteor.call("setEventVsColor", eventData._id, "rgb(" + rgb.r.toString() + "," + rgb.g.toString() + "," + rgb.b.toString() + ")");
            });
        });
    });
```

Whenever the data retrieved by the helper is modified, I expect the template to re-render, since some of the onRendered functionality (excluded in this example) depends on the new data. But onRendered never triggers. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** After using Jankapunkt's solution, some of the onRendered components trigger for every one of the parent template's collection items, not just the item passed to the child template.

Comment: Can you please add your onRendered function that should Trigger?

Comment: It doesn't re-render regardless of the onRendered content. For example I can simply put in a console.log("RENDERING EVENT"); and it will only print it once initially, then never again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for reactive data updates using `Template.currentData()` within an `autorun` (Tracker) computation:

```js
Template["page-event"].onRendered(function() {
  const instance = this
  instance.autorun(() => {
    const data = Template.currentData() // reactive data source
    // ... process data
  })
});
```

According to [the BlazeJS documentation](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Blaze-TemplateInstance-autorun) it should work for `onCreated`, as well as `onRendered`

Comment: Ok, this works, but the content of onRendered seems to play a role after all. I modified the example to exemplify a colorPicker I'm using. This now triggers for EVERY item of the parent template which I have previously Rendered, not just for the selected event item on the child template.

Comment: By item I mean the published documents of my "Event" collection, of which I pass only one to the child template. At least that's the intention...

Comment: This might be due to the fact that, upon changing the data passed to the child, the old child template is still somewhere in the DOM after re-render? OnDestroyed doesn't trigger when switching between child templates. I managed to change some of the listeners in the onRendered and did it the "meteor" way, but for some plugins I'm having difficulties doing that....

Comment: Hey , guys i am facing the same issue to render new data for my graphs . even though it is reactive . my autorun doesnt update when the data changes

Comment: @VinayKashyap please open a new question and add the code that you think should trigger the autorun.

Comment: @Jankapunkt https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65690520/graph-does-not-update-automatically-when-the-data-is-changed.

Comment: @Jankapunkt i have added the question . i hope you can help me out

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `onRendered` function is not reactive, it does not reevaluate on data change. It is specifically meant to only render once. What you want is a regular helper function, that you then use in your template.

```
Template["page-event"].helpers({
  foo(): { console.log("RENDERING EVENT"); }
});
```

This will re-run on data change.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure how that would work. My onRendered is indeed pretty long, including color pickers and text editors etc. I've modified the example to reflect a part of that. How would I integrate all this with a helper?